# WPF Loading animation

Tags: wpf, search, animation, asynchronous

I Have a **ListView** with many Items that is to be loaded in search. 
And I'd like to provide user the richer user interface so that when loading, **I'd display a rotating circle (known from AJAX waiting)**.

I realize that I'll have to go into Threads or something, but as I've never done this before in WPF, I'm sure there is something better than Threads in WPF (or a simpe BackgroundWorker).

Anyways, the point is to display that animation while loading. 
Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I've got a working solution now.

I have a **UserControl** that contains that animation. It is located somewhere in my XAML code like this: `<customControls:LoadingAnimation x:Name="LoadingAnimation" />`. This control is loaded when neede by calling

```
LoadingAnimation.Show();
```

Now when I click on a Button to do the time-consuming work, before I call BeginInvoke() I 
load that animation.

Then when the hard work is finished I call `LoadingAnimation.Hide().`
Very simple! I add code for the others:

```
private void SearchClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     LoadingAnimation.Show();

     new StringDelegate(DoSearch).BeginInvoke("TextToSearch", null, null);
}

private void DoSearch(string searchText)
{
    object result = /* Do the time consuming work */    

    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
         new ResultDelagate(UpdateUserInterface), result);
}

private void UpdateUserInterface(object result)
{
    LoadingAnimation.Hide();            

    DataContext = result as /* what you want */;
}
```

Comment: Just have a status, IsSearching, and use datatriggers to show and hide the user control